# Symfony 4: Struggling outside of Controller and Autowiring

Tags: php, symfony4

I have done this countless times now and perhaps it's because autowiring and dependency injection is too complex for me and I just need to work around it, but after consistently searching, I'm still having problems understanding the right way to fix this.

I have this class where I'm trying to create a query from - this is all great and fine as long as I extend "Controller" - as soon as I stray from this, I either get:

```
$em = new EntityManagerInterface();
    $query = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT m FROM App:Main m')
            ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
    print_r($query);
```

*This is obvious, you cannot instansiate an interface*

> Cannot instatiate interface Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface

Or:

```
Use App\Util\Db\Dbhelper;
$db = $this->container->get(DbHelper::class);
$result = $db->allMains();
```

> Too few arguments to function App\Util\Db|DbHelper::__construct(), 0 passed 1 expected

The other classes are expecting the dependency injection of EntityManagerInterface obviously.  All help is greatly appreciated, I don't know why I cannot seem to wrap my head around this properly.

DbHelper Class:

```
namespace App\Util\Db;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use App\Entity\Main;

class DbHelper
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getNames()
    {
        $names = $this->em->getRepository(Main::class)->findAll();
        foreach ($names as $name) {
            echo $name->getName();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try Autowire'ing your service as well, inside your Controller or Command. It's like a chain. If you don't want to do it this way, you have to 'inject' the required service yourself, as found here https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html

Comment: When you say inside your Controller or Command how do you mean?  I have the service defined as public in the services.yaml file and any class that extends "Controller" has absolutely no issue with this.

Comment: With your edit: `$db = $this->container->get(DbHelper::class);` is kinda deprecated (and is bad practice). You should implement DbHelper inside your `__construct` where you call it.

Comment: @DominicWehrmann - thanks, but that doesn't make a difference - the same error is given.

Comment: First, an interface `EntityManagerInterface` is a contract describing what  methods a class should provide. It's not a concrete class, so it cannot be instantiated. You'd need to instatiate the class that implements the contract. Next, can you post the code for the class you're talking about?